# Decision boundary in XOR multilayer perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, xor, perceptron

I am trying to simulate the XOR problem using the multilayer perceptron. So far, I've learnt that it's not linearly separable and therefore it needs a hidden layer. What I cannot understand is which neurons determines the decision boundaries. As far as I have seen, it seems that the hidden layer neurons output is considered, but then if I change the weights only to the input of the output layer, the decision boundaries will not change.
This has confused me, and would like to take help in understanding this.

Also attaching an image:
[Graph of the XOR classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2408H.png.)

w11 w12 b1 w21 w22 b2 v1 v2 and b3 are parameters of first hidden neuron, second hidden neuron and the output neuron respectively.
When I change v1 and/or v2, the decision boundaries remains the same but the error rate changes:

[New graph when v2 changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1nlt.png.)

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: It appears you have two hidden layers so you have an over-determined problem. XOR only needs one hidden layer. It isn't clear how your weights are mapped but it is likely that the one you are changing is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Changing v1 and v2 will not change decision boundaries.

There are two nodes in hidden layer. A vague understanding is that each node simulates one of the two lines of decision boundary shown in image. The last node performs an operation which is a kind of intersection of decision regions simulated by nodes in hidden layer. Try changing *w11, w21* and it shall affect one of the lines in decision boundary and change *w12,w22* and it will affect the other line.

By changing v1 and v2, there is no affect on decision regions produced by nodes in hidden layer. Thus, there is no affect on final decision boundary( which is intersection of individual decision boundaries).